# Cannot Update EAV Unique Attribute

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, eav

I have a custom product attribute `custom_attr` that I created using `InstallData.php` and set its `unique` value to `true`. Now, I am trying to set it back to `false` in `UpgradeData.php` but the changes are not working. What could be wrong with my code? I have checked the database table `eav_attribute` and the `is_unique` field is not updated to `0`.

Magento version: 2.4.3-p1

InstallData.php:

```
namespace SomeVendor\AModule\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'custom_attr',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Enable Custom Attr',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'unique' => false, /** <- this was true */
                'apply_to' => 'simple',
            ]
        );

    }
}
```

UpgradeData.php:

```
namespace SomeVendor\AModule\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if ($context->getVersion() && version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.0') < 0) {

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'custom_attr',
                [
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'label' => 'Enable Commerce Connector Tag',
                    'input' => 'boolean',
                    'class' => '',
                    'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'default' => '',
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                    'unique' => false, /** <- this was true */
                    'apply_to' => 'simple',
                ]
            );
        }

        if ($context->getVersion() && version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.1') < 0) {

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'custom_attr',
                'unique',
                false,
                null
            );
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="SomeVendor_AModule" setup_version="1.1.1" />
</config>
```

After making the changes I ran the commands:

```
bin/magento set:up
bin/magento set:di:com
bin/magento s:s:d -f
bin/magento ind:rei
bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the cause of the issue, and it is kind of a confusing thing to have in Magento.
In setting up the attribute, `unique` code is used to set up the attribute. However, this code in the database is written as `is_unique` so I tried that in the `UpgradeData.php` and it worked:

```
if ($context->getVersion() && version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.1') < 0) {

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'custom_attr',
                'is_unique', /** <- was 'unique' */
                false,
                null
            );
        }
```

I was unsure whether Magento accepted the previous code in `InstallData.php` so I removed the attribute from the database with the module in `setup_module` and did a `set:up` command. After that, I checked the database, and the value of `is_unique` is set the same as the value in `InstallData.php`.

#### In summary

Magento accepted `unique` as the code when calling `AddAttribute` and did not accept it (without showing any error) when calling `UpdateAttribute` but accepted `is_unique` code.